# Unapplied migrations when moving django app from one server to another

Tags: django

There is a Django app, which primary responsibility is creating reports from database and updating tables in the same database.

It is currently running on server A. I now copied the application to the server B and point it to the same database. It is picking up all the tables/functionality just fine.

The only thing that really worries me, is that when i start a python development server on server B, it gives me ***You have unapplied migrations*** warning. I am pretty sure that i do not need to make any changes to my database - I am just pointing to the same database people still use from server A - so I am pretty sure that i need not make any migrations.

Should i just ignore that warning? What would be the best practice migration-wise when just copying an app from server A to server B?

Comment: Oops, yes don't do `--fake`, got it mixed up with the description for `--dry-run` for a different command (which also won't help)

Comment: @Alasdair Do you know how django defines which migrations where applied and which weren't?

Comment: @Alasdair On server A there is an X in front of each migration, which means that they all were applied

Comment: I believe the Django compares the migrations files with the `django_migrations` database table. If the migration files are the same on both servers, and both servers are accessing the same `django_migrations` table, I don't understand why you would get the 'unapplied migrations' warning on one machine but not the other.

Comment: @Alas thank you for the tip. At least i acquainted myself with that table :) Will try researching further into it

Comment: @Alasdair With your help i managed to find the issue. Contents of the `migrations` folder on server A are not identical to the contents of the same folder on server B. The reason for that was poorly managed version control on server A. Thanks :)

Comment: Great, I've added the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the migration files are the same on both servers.

If both servers have the same migration files, and both servers are accessing the same database, then you shouldn't get the 'unapplied migrations' warning on one server but not the other.

Comment: Confirm that files synchronization solved the issue.